# How can I disable email tracking in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tracking

I found out that someone can actually track if I deleted an email they sent to me in Outlook or not.

Are there are any ways to disable this feature?

Comment: I believe most of the tracking features are handled on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

Advanced features like this (recalling email, email auditing)  are not available to the "home" user.  They are part of corporate environments that use Exchange server.  If you are just using Outlook to read your GMail or Yahoo mail, you have nothing to worry about.  However, if this is at your work and these features are enabled, you have no control over them, as they are part of the Group Policy.

Comment: Hi, I use this at work (Exchange server). So I have no control over this ? (to not let people know that I deleted their "tracked" email)

Comment: The information can only be checked within the scope of the Exchange server and domain.  So, someone outside the company could not tell if you deleted an email, however within your company, the administrators can know exactly what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

there are tracking applications based on view image principle: http://www.outlook-apps.com/track-if-an-email-has-been-read/

To disable that kind of a behavior, in outlook 2010:
go to options -> Trust Center
click on Trust Center Settings... button
Select Automatic Download, check "Don't Download pictures" and uncheck the rest